# Why can't I access this folder?

Tags: command-line, ls, cd-command

Why can't I access the folder `/website1`?

```
juozas@personal:/opt/lampp/htcdocs$ ls
website1
juozas@personal:/opt/lampp/htcdocs$ cd /website1
bash: cd: /website1: No such file or directory
juozas@personal:/opt/lampp/htcdocs$ cd /website1
bash: cd: /website1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @EliahKagan I have accepted it. Sorry i found this too late, I would need to write this by hand at this time. I will definitely write more quality questions next time!

Comment: @JuozasG Wouldn't the same wrong commands harmlessly produce the same results if you ran them again? It's up to you -- you don't have to edit this -- but it seems to me that you probably could do so without difficulty by just running what you ran before.

Comment: you forgot the slash between opt and lampp `cd /opt/lampp/htcdocs/website1` or the relative `cd website1`

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry it took me so long. I did what you recommended, in an attempt to justify my shitty original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

```
cd /opt/lampp/htcdocs/website1
```

or

```
cd ./website1
```

You missed a slash between `/opt` and `lampp` in the first two attempts, and you're trying to access a nonexistent folder at the root of the filesystem in the third. `/` doesn't refer to the current directory, but `.` does.

Comment: Or, instead of `cd ./website1`, just `cd website1`.